# Keep sharpness of bitmap colors in stretched imageview

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

Is it possible to keep the colors of the bitmap in a stretched imageview sharp if this bitmap contains only the colors black and white?
Currently what i get is the bitmap with blurred edges.
I think it would make sense to keep the sharpness of the colors without resizing the bitmap

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but :)

You should provide screenshots with your question so we can see what you're talking about. Anyway, drawables in Android aren't scaled very well so it is normal if you get some blurry effet on a resized bitmap.

You should use the different drawables (drawable-hdpi, -mdpi, xhdpi, ...) folders of your project to provide different versions of your images to the system. The right resource will always be chosen depending on the device screen.